# Group of order 144

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order 144, and let $N_{1}$, $N_{2}$, and $N_{3}$ be of order 12 normal subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $N_{1}\cap N_{2}=N_{2}\cap N_{3}=N_{1}\cap N_{3}=\left\{e\right\}$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$. Show that $N_{1},N_{2}$,and $N_{3}$ are all abelian, and so is $G$. (Hint: Let $A$ be a group, and let both $B$ and $C$ be normal subgroups of $G$ so that $B\cap C=\left\{e\right\}$. Then, $xy=yx$ for any $x\in B$ and $y\in C$.)

It is easy to show that $G=N_{1}N_{2}=N_{2}N_{3}=N_{1}N_{3}$.

I tried to prove using the above facts and the given hint, but there is no further progress.

Give some advice! Thank you!

Comment: I'll give a hint. Showing $N_1$ is abelian: Let $x,y\in N_1$. As $G=N_2N_3$, we also have $x=x_1x_2$ with $x_1\in N_2$ and $x_2\in N_3$. Can you use this and the hint to show that $xy=yx$?

Comment: I think you need to assume that $N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$ are all normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Correct. I missed.

Comment: Suppose $x \in B, y \in C$ (as in your hint). What can you say about $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$?